# Could not separate implementation and interface

Tags: c++, interface, header

I am unable to compile the following files.
I am trying to pass the name and age to an object and after checking and assigning each age to proper category(adult, kid...) then i am trying to print it.

My 3 files are following:

**The first 1:**

```
//cannot access private member declared in class Person
//No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include "person2.h"

void getData(Person&);
void displayData(Person&);

int main(){
    Person p;
    getData(p);
    displayData(p);
}

void getData(Person& p){
    cout<< "Enter the name: ";
    cin>> p.name;
    cout<<"Enter the age: ";
    int age;
    cin>> age;
    p.setAge(age);
    p.ageGroup = p.determineAgeGroup(age);
}
void displayData(Person& p){
    cout<<p.name<< " is in the group of " << p.ageGroup <<endl;
}
```

**The second one:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Person {
public:
    string name;
    string ageGroup;
    void setAge(int&);
    string getAge();
    string getAgeGroup(int);

private:
    int age;
    string determineAgeGroup(int );
```

};

**The third one:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "person2.h"
using namespace std;

void Person::setAge(int& a){
    if(a<0) cout<< "No";
}
string Person::getAge(){
    return age;
}
string Person::determineAgeGroup(int a){
    if(a>= 65) return "Senior";
    else if(a<65 & a>= 20) return "Adult";
    else if(a<20 & a>= 13) return "Teen";
    else return "Kid";  
}
string Person::getAgeGroup(int a){
    return determineAgeGroup(a);<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Why couldn't you compile them? Did you get an error? What error?

Comment: I couldn't post the image of the my errors because I'm a newbie here but I have whole bunch of errors.

Comment: How about tying in the first one, or explaining what it is and what you've tried to do to fix it.

Comment: I typed some above the first one but those are just a few of a hundred lines of errors. I think it's the matter of accessing private function. But I'm not sure.

Comment: This isn't valid : `<<end;` Pretty sure you meant `<< endl;` if this is a typo, then post the *real* code.

Comment: @MinhNguyen It sounds like you don't know what your question is yet. Keep working on the first error you get. Perhaps create a small, contained example that reproduces the error. In the process, you'll either solve it or figure out what your question actually is. But it sounds like it's too early for you to ask a question since you don't know yet what the issue is.

Comment: I edited the file, and the error as well. It says "Cannot access private member declared in class Person". Any solution?

Comment: Create a public function that returns the age group or use memberspaces.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

- endl instead of end in displayData
- declare int age in getData and pass that value to p.setAge
- return value from getAge should be an int
- make determineAgeGroup() public or call determineAgeGroup() from a member function like setAge() or call your public function getAgeGroup().

This should at least get you compiling...

**Note:** The final edit that solved the problem was bullet point number 4, in particular calling the public function getAgeGroup().

Comment: Well, you can't call it from getData then.  You could call determineAgeGroup from one of the member functions (like when you set age?)

Comment: That's why I had getAgeGroup() to get the returned value from determineAgeGroup(). That's my I ideal but it seems not working...

Comment: If that's your intent (I won't comment on style choice here), then call getAgeGroup() from getData() instead of calling determineAgeGroup().

Comment: Great!  And welcome to SO. If an answer fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist.

Comment: No, not really, the problem was from this code line :p.ageGroup = p.determineAgeGroup(age); I should have called getAgeGroup(age) instead. btw, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will edit the question to emphasize the edit that ultimately solved your problem.